How to randomly select a number from a set of numbers?
I am trying to make a function which returns a random number from among a set of specified numbers (comma seperated) in React. I mean,
randomInside(10,20,25,45) // desired output is one of the numbers, e.g. 25

My try was:
const randomInside = (numbers) => {
    const array = [numbers]
    const newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
    return array[newIndex]
}

but this gives the first item in all occurences. How can I fix this?

I you want to access all of the parameters passed into a function, look into rest parameters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

@DBS This post helped a lot, thanks man I did it.

You need to collect all arguments into an array if you want to handle it as such. One way of doing so would involve the "rest" parameter ...:


console.log(randomInside(10,20,25,45)) // desired output is taking one of the numbers, i.e 25

function randomInside(...array){
  const newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
  return array[newIndex]
}



